# Outlook API v2.0 getEvents concurrency litmit

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using outlook api v2.0 rest api to perform crud operations against calendars and events and have started hitting a rate limit issue.

This one for example is hitting the [calendarview endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#get-events):

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/{CALENDAR_ID}/calendarview
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS**

- Rate-Limit-Limit=10000
- Rate-Limit-Remaining=9982
- Rate-Limit-Reset=2019-10-23T15:27:11.409Z
- Retry-After=1
- RateLimit-Exceeded=MailboxConcurrency
- RateLimit-Scope=Mailbox
- Transfer-Encoding=chunked
- X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus=429
- X-Powered-By=ASP.NET
- X-RUM-Validated=1

**RESPONSE BODY**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ApplicationThrottled",
        "message": "Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit."
    }
}
```

At first I thought it was the 10.000 requests per 10 minutes period but it seems I am hitting a different one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is showing that you've hit the mailboxconcurency limit. There is a limit of 4 concurrent requests as per the documentation.

Is there any reason you are using this API rather than Microsoft Graph also?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#outlook-service-limits

Comment: Documentation says 4 concurrent request are for beta endpoints but there is no indication the one I am assuming is beta anywhere?

Comment: According to Outlook docs for that endpoint there is:

- A beta version: `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/calendarview`
- A v2.0 version: `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview`

Given so I was expecting the concurrent requests limit would only apply to the former. Am I wrong?

I am really keen on moving to the new Graph API but the docs say Graph V1 matches Outlook v2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph#api-versions) so I was hoping I can get the concurrency issue fixed before migrating.

Comment: The concurrent limit is for both v2.0 of outlook.office.com AND graph.microsoft.com . I have just confirmed this with the architect.